# Why does bean referenced in @ConditionalOnExpression not add to context before expression gets evaluated?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-3

Using spring-boot 3.0.4 with Java 17 and I am adding a JavaBean with inner list property to the context. and afterwards trying to add other dependent beans only if previous bean's inner list property has required size. tried to implement this condition with spring's `@ConditionalOnExpression` but getting following error.

Configuration Class

```java
public class PulledClientConfig{

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnExpression("#{pullConfigProperties.targets().size() != 0}")
    public ClientMetricsService pulledClientMetricsService(RoutableMetricsRegistry registry, KubernetesClientProperties kubernetesClientProperties, CacheAccessOperation cacheAccessOperation, @Qualifier("applicationTaskExecutor") ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor){
        return new PulledClientMetricsService(registry,kubernetesClientProperties,cacheAccessOperation,threadPoolTaskExecutor);
    }


    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnExpression("#{pullConfigProperties.targets().size() != 0}")
    public PulledClientMetricsManager pulledClientMetricsManager(PullConfigProperties pullConfigProperties, @Qualifier("pulledClientMetricsService") ClientMetricsService pulledClientMetricsService){
        return new PulledClientMetricsManager(pullConfigProperties, pulledClientMetricsService);
    }


    @Bean
    public PullConfigProperties pullConfigProperties(Validator validator, ObjectMapper mapper, ResourceLoader resourceLoader){
        log.info("Pull config file found.Validating.");
        PullConfigProperties properties= null;
        // some population logic for properties
        return properties;
    }
```

Error is

`EL1008E: Property or field 'pullConfigProperties' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?`

With debugging I understand conditional expressions evaluated **before** context is populated with required beans. What I don't get in spring-boot 3.1.3 expressions evaluted **after** required beans are created. Are there any core changes about evaluation of conditional expressions referencing beans between spring boot versions?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at SpEL [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#d0e12015), it seems like the way to reference a bean is via `@beanName`.  So maybe it should've been:

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("@pullConfigProperties.targets().size() != 0")
```